# Cannot get replies to show up in activities

Tags: civimail

CiviCRM 5.14.0

I have bounce processing working fine but I am trying to track replies. Replies are sent using a VERP address and are being received in the correct mailbox as defined in the CiviMail Administer/CiviMail/Mail Accounts settings.

I run the Process Bounces job and I expect to see an entry in the activities for anyone who replies to the email but I only see the outgoing mail under the type BULK EMAIL. The replies are correctly being moved from the Inbox to the Processed folder that CiviCRM created.

**Replies are being counted correctly in the report for the mailing but are not being added to the contacts' activities.**

There is a setting under System Administration/CiviMail/CiviCRM Component Settings that seems to be in error. If it is checked, it disables VERP replies. Leaving it unchecked causes replies to use VERP. This seems to be a bug.

[image]

**A Workaround**

As I have access to the Postfix server, I was able to move the processed emails from the "Bouncer" mailbox to the Inbox of the "Activities" mailbox then run the fetch-activities job. This successfully processed the replies and inserted them in the activities table.

Comment: I have noticed that the report is showing there were no replies, however, I have replied and the reply was received in the default mailbox.

Comment: were you able to look at the email address that it sent to did it have -r or similar in there and i actually think what you might want to do is run the bounce processor job not the inbound email job

Comment: Seamus Lee: we did discuss this in Mattermost. I did not subscribe to the two folders CiviMail created, "processed" and "ignored". One I did, the replies were reported in the CiviMail report for the mailing. They are still not being recorded in the activities for the contacts that replied.

Comment: I was confused but subsequently learned that it is the process bounces job that processed the replies, not the process inbound email.

Comment: Received in Mattermost;

@dmgray0325 that will happen if the following occurs

The reply eventually ends up in the email to activity IMAP mailbox
the process incoming email happens.
Perhaps if you can if you can set up a rule in your email handling that moves an email with -r or -reply in the to email from the Bounce Mailboxe's processed folder to the email to activity  mailbox

Comment: The last comment offers a partial solution. I believe CiviCRM should do this automatically.

I move the mail from /var/mail/vhosts/vietfeir.com/civimail/.INBOX.civimail.processed to /var/mail/vhosts/vietfeir.com/activities/cur 

I then ran the Process Inbound Emails job and the mails were moved to the Process folder and were recorded as Activities successfully. The activity type is Inbound Email and viewing it shows the content of the reply

Comment: This, of course, is not ideal. I manage my own Postfix server so I can write a script to move the mails and then let fetch-activities handle the rest. I believe this all should be handled by CiviCRM and, when I used Sparkpost, it handled it like I expected. At this time, I do not want to use Sparkpost. 

This is still an open question: Why doesn't CiviCRM handle this properly?

Comment: Just to summarise - your issue is that replies are being counted in the report but not being added as activities?

Comment: Yes, Luke. I'll update the original question to clarify that I

Comment: I have the same issue on 5.48.2. I don't understand if whether there is a way to solve it in CiviCRM or how to do it.
I would expect the fetch_bounces job to create the task.
The forward-to doesn't work for me either....